# page too large for window

Tags: html, css, window, size

For some reason my page defaults to being slightly larger then the window containing it, regardless of the window's size.

I'm trying to make it so that page at default will fit the browser window, not be larger.

http://jsfiddle.net/VTKvM/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div> 
        <div id="description"> 
            <p id="content"> The content goes here </p>
        </div>
        <div class="title"> WEB DESIGN </div>
            <div class="tile-container">
                <div class="box">   
                    <div class="logo a1"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="logo a2"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="logo a3"></div> 
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="logo a4"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="logo a5"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">   
                    <div class="logo a6"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="logo a7"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="logo a8"></div> 
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="logo a9"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="logo a10"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">   
                    <div class="logo a11"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="logo a12"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="logo a13"></div>    
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="logo a14"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="logo a15"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="logo a16"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="logo a17"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="box"> </div>
            </div> <!-- end tileContainer -->


   <div id="footer">
        <div class="taskBarHolderBottom"> test </div>
        <div id="bottomBar"> test </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
   margin: auto;
   padding: 0px;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}

#description {
   min-width: 120;
   max-width: 1920;

   height: 10.625em;
   background-color: #666666;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-top: 70px;
}
.tile-container{
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: auto;
}
.box {
   width: 191px;
   height: 145px;
   margin: 4px;
   float: left;
   background-color: black;
   opacity: 0.2;

}
.box:hover{
   background-color:#EF6939;
   opacity: 1;
      overflow: hidden;

}

.logo:hover{
   background-color:#EF6939;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.logo {
   width: 191px;
   height: 145px;
   margin: 4px;
   float: left;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}

#bottomBar {
   background-color: green;
   height: 65px;
   width:100%;
}

.a1 {
   background-image: url(artizone.png);
}
.a2 {
   background-image: url(careoregon.png);
}
.a3 {
   background-image: url(concur.png);
}
.a4 {
   background-image: url(corbis.png);
}
.a5 {
   background-image: url(dex.png);
}
.a6 {
   background-image: url(digitalrealty.png);
}
.a7 {
   background-image: url(KCHA.png);
}
.a8 {
   background-image: url(miamifreezone.png);
}
.a9 {
   background-image: url(microsoft.png);
}
.a10 {
   background-image: url(microsoftexchange.png);
}
.a11 {
   background-image: url(microsoftinvestorrelations.png);
}
.a12 {
   background-image: url(microsoftlearning.png);
}
.a13 {
   background-image: url(mscustomerexperience.png);
}
.a14 {
   background-image: url(Premera.png);
}
.a15 {
   background-image: url(stanford.png);
}
.a16 {
   background-image: url(tmobile.png);
}
.a17 {
   background-image: url(weyerhaeuser.png);
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome/Mac.

Comment: Note: `min-width` and `max-width` are missing `px` for `#description`.

Comment: So you want the scrollbar only on the content and the header/footer to always be visible?